# Extracting particular value from url

Tags: regex, url

I have u URI like:
http://www.website.com/categoryName-890/categoryName-987/?brandName=sony

Now i want this both **categoryName-890** and **categoryName-987** from this url.

Can someone tell me how can i get these fields.

Comment: I guess **categoryName** is a placeholder, but will it, apart for the ending, always be the same in both positions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident that the URL stays in a similar format, this should capture the two parts between the slashes as groups.

`http://[^/]+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/`

This can be modified further to change protocols, or make the domain part more strict based on your usage. Essentially it is just looking for non slash and slash characters.

Alternatively you could specify categoryName in the regular expression such as

`http://[^/]+/(categoryName-\d+)/(categoryName-\d+)/`

it really depends on your requirements and how the URLs are formatted.